# SQL query to accomplish the following this task?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have the tables with columns as follows:

```
Table 1 (Instance Table):

Name | Id | Duration | ConfigurationID


Table 2 (Class Table):

Configuration | Id | Last Changed
```

In my table 2, I have rows with Configuration names as follows. Names are code-generated.:

```
Test 1
Copy of Test 1
Copy of Test 1 (1)
Copy of Test 1 (2)
Copy of Test 1 (3)
...
...
Test 2
Copy of Test 2
Copy of Test 2 (1)
Copy of Test 2 (2)
Copy of Test 2 (3)
```

Table 1 contains the instances of different configurations. For example rows 1-15 may be instances of Configuration Test 1, 16 - 30 instances of Configuration Copy of Test 1 etc.

I want to find the average duration of all the instances that are of a configuration type and all of its copies i.e row/columns as follows:

```
Row/Column 1: Avg Duration of instances of type Test 1 and all of its copies (Copy of Test 1, Copy of Test 1(1), ...Copy of Test 1 (3));

Row/Column 2: Avg Duration of instances of type Test 2 and all of its copies (Copy of Test 1, Copy of Test 1(1), ...Copy of Test 1 (3));
....
```

I need some help on how to write the SQL query to accomplish this task. 
So far I have this:

```
SELECT AVG(i.[Duration]/1000.0) as [Avg Duration (s)]
FROM [Table 1] i
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table 2] p
ON i.[ConfigurationID] = p.Id 
WHERE i.Name LIKE '(Copy of)%'
GROUP BY i.Name
```

Comment: So, the only way to know if a configuration is a copy of another is because of the `Copy of` prefix?, that's not really a good way. How can I know, for instance, if `Copy of Test 11 (1)` is not a copy of `Test 1`?

Comment: Also, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?, please use the appropriate tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(i.Duration / 1000) as "Avg Duration (s)"
FROM "Table 1" i
    LEFT JOIN "Table 2" p
        ON i.ConfigurationID = p.Id 
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN i.Name LIKE 'C%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(i.Name, 9), ' ', 2)
    ELSE i.Name
END
```

The "interesting" part is `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(i.Name, 9), ' ', 2)`.

We cut the initial `'Copy of '` and then get everything before the second space.

---

Your question is tagged [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). This answer uses [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think the syntax is wrong here. Shouldn't the second parameter of `LEFT` be an int and not a string?

Comment: @AlvinThompson, see revised answer.

Comment: Actually, the use of square brackets (`[]`) instead of backticks for the column names hints heavily to SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak, you're right...I had never seen brackets in MySQL...I figured they were legit.

Comment: My comment was more because of the use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in your answer, a function that doesn't exists in SQL Server.

Comment: @Lamak, yes,  but I already answered the question once; I don't think I'm going to do it again :/